# Drawing a cross shape background on Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I've spent quite a while looking for a way to do this but I've come up with nothing that could best solve this.

I'm developing an android game an I'd like the main activity's design to have a cross shaped graphic on the background ([similar to this](http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/10/17/11/patterns-26484_640.png)) with a couple of buttons overlaid on top.

A bit of an open question but what would be the best way to approach this? Creating a custom view class, design the background as an image, or a combination of any other technique?

Comment: use a ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a simple shape I would go with something like [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable). However, the example image you showed has quite enough detail that I would just go with a `.png` resource file as the background resource.